# Как сгенерировать файл pdf из html?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Подскажите пожалуйста, нужно сделать чтобы пользователь мог скачать выбранные товары в корзине в формате pdf. То есть условно есть массив объектов(товаров) и кнопка в корзине "Скачать". При нажатии кнопки каким-то образом должен генерироваться файл с конкретными товарами, в файле должны быть инфо о товаре(картинки, название и тд). Всё это должно происходить на клиенте.
Подскажите пожалуйста актуальные библиотеки или инструменты с помощью которых смогу такое реализовать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Может вот такая статейка тебя вдохновит... https://dev.to/finallynero/generating-pdf-documents-in-react-using-react-pdf-4ka7

Comment: Это на стороне сервера делается. Я вот недавно использовал либу для nodeJs "node-html-pdf" https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf?activeTab=readme

Comment: Спасибо большое, отличная статья, нашёл все ответы)